# How to copy text from one layer to another using script in photoshop with same formatting?

Tags: copy-paste, layer, photoshop-script

I am trying to copy one text layer content to another layer. I am able to copy content but same format is not coming, i.e bold text become same as source text as regular.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use Duplicate layer?

Comment: Yes, actually I want to merge two layers content into one layer with keeping the same formatting.